# Access the date text of input element with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

When visiting the website this element contains the date: ***20210930***

```
<input placeholder="yyyymmdd" ng-class="{'mark-red': relatedDocument.documentDate == null}" title="yyyyMMdd" data-autoclose="1" bs-datepicker="" data-date-format="yyyyMMdd" data-date-type="number" class="form-control importInputHalf ng-valid ng-valid-date ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" data-max-date="today" ng-model="relatedDocument.documentDate" ng-disabled="editDisabled || relatedDocument.documentDuplicated || (isDocumentAlreadyUsed(relatedDocument) &amp;&amp; relatedDocument.rex) || relatedDocument.correctionCloneLocked" ng-change="documentChanged(relatedDocument,'documentDate')">
```

But when I try to access this information through Selenium with the following code it returns empty:

```
date = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "// *[@id='out']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[5]/input").text
```

Is there a way to access this data?

Comment: Try `date.get_attribute('value')`

Answer (score 0):

The text *20210930* isn't the *`innerText`* but the ***value*** within. So *text* attribute won't be able to retrive it. You need to use `get_attribute("value")` inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='yyyymmdd'][title='yyyyMMdd'][ata-date-format='yyyyMMdd'][data-max-date='today']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='yyyymmdd' and @title='yyyyMMdd'][@data-date-format='yyyyMMdd' and @data-max-date='today']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```